# A mechanism or CraftBukkit plugin to not allow building or mining in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to teach students how to program JavaScript inside Minecraft with [ScriptCraft](https://github.com/walterhiggins/ScriptCraft/). It's been amazing, except for the fact that even my most focused students get so distracted with playing minecraft instead of learning to program. I need a way for them to essentially not be able to do anything in Minecraft if it wasn't done programmatically through JavaScript.

ScriptCraft requires running a CraftBukkit server. Is there a mechanism to do disallow mining or building in Minecraft, CraftBukkit or a CraftBukkit plugin?

Comment: Does `/gamemode 2` not solve the problem?  Don't give them a tool, and they can't get most blocks.  If they don't have blocks, it's hard for them to build anything.

Comment: For reference, gamemmode 2 is [Adenture mode](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Adventure), where you cannot harvest any block without the matching tool (shovels for dirt, axes for wood, etc).

Comment: `/gamemode 2` doesn't solve the problem, but it does sound better than modes 0 or 1. The issue is distraction and there's still some distraction in Adventure mode. ScriptCraft also requires users have `op` privileges. So very easy for users to change their gamemode. I'm not too worried about that as this can be a more serious violation of our rules.

Comment: I would add another upvote to both the question and answer if I could.  Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PermissionsEx](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/permissionsex/) and [ModifyWorld](https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/wiki/Modifyworld) should solve this problem quite nicely.

*PermissionsEx* is a general permissions plugin and *ModifyWorld* is an optional part of PEX:

> [ModifyWorld] provides the possibility to control players
> abilities, such as destroying/placing blocks, riding carts/boats or
> even getting spotted by mobs and much more. Disabled by default.

The [PEX wiki](https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/wiki) has a nice series of articles explaining exactly how to setup PEX with modofyworld. I suggest you follow along the tutorial so you understand how to install and configure PEX. Then when you get to the "Basic-Permissions-Setup" page, use my suggested configuration instead of theirs.

config.yml:

```
permissions:
    backends:                            <- Backend Definition Section
        file:                            <- File Based Backend Section
            file: permissions.yml        <- File Name To Use
    backend: file                        <- Backend To Use On Start
    superperms:                          <- Settings For SuperPerm Support
        enable-wildcards: true
        disable-unmatched: false
        enable: true
        debug: false
        compatibility-mode: false
    createUserRecords: false             <- Other Settings
    allowOps: false
    debug: false
    basedir: plugins/PermissionsEx       <- Directory Name To Use
```

Once this is done, it sounds like this ought to work as your permissions.yml:

```
groups:
    #default group
    default:
        default: true
        prefix: '&0(&4Default&0)&7 '
        permissions:
        - -modifyworld.*    #All permissions, equivalent to current setup

    #students
    students:
        default: false
        permissions:
        - modifyworld.chat
        - modifyworld.sneak
        - modifyworld.sprint
        - modifyworld.blocks.interact.69    #Allow levers
        - -modifyworld.*

    #teacher
    teacher:
        default: false
        permissions:
        - modifyworld.*
        - permissions.*

users:
    SomeStudent:
        group:
        - students
    SomeOtherStudent:
        group:
        - students
    YetAnotherStudent:
        group:
        - students
    at01:
        group:
        - Teacher
```

This puts the listed students into the students group, which denies all permissions except those specifically listed. You may want to browse the [block ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values) list and allow `modifyworld.blocks.interact.<Block ID>` with some more of them (e.g. chests, buttons, doors). Make sure to use the "Dec" value listed, not the "Hex". You may also want to browse the [permissions list](https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/wiki/Modifyworld) to check for other things you want to allow students to do.

If you miss any student names they will be allowed to do everything, which is equivalent to the permissions they have right now. If any students are in this group when they chat their name will be prefixed by "default" in coloured letters, which will alert you to fix this error. You can fix this by typing in game using your op account:

```
/pex user <username> group add students
```

Note: I specifically did *not* make the default group the limited one for students. PEX often messes up plugins by trying to apply permissions to the actions of the plugins (so in this case ScriptCraft might have the same limitations as the students). I have no idea if this is a problem for ScriptCraft, you could test it by moving all the student permissions to default and seeing if ScriptCraft still works.

**In Response To Comment**: I've modified the config to account for all students needing to be op. By using `allowOps: false` this tells PEX that it *should* apply permissions rules even to ops. With this setting on you will *probably* need to allow access to all of the ScriptCraft commands, simply add the relevant permission nodes to the relevant groups.

Comment: `ScriptCraft` requires students to be `op`s. I know that may allow them to circumvent any permissions settings, but that's ok. Purposely circumventing our permissions would be a serious violation and we can make that clear. However, would this work with PermissionsEx and ModifyWorld? You mentioned making yourself an `op` "ensures that you will retain all permissions no matter what you configure PEX to do"

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: Excellent, I'll try this out shortly!

Comment: Nothing really works here. I installed the PermissionsEx plugin, which comes with the ModifyWorld plugin. I copied your config.yml and permissions.yml text above. I get an error when booting the server that there are no groups defined, so I simply add a `groups:` line at the top of permissions.yml. That solves it. Looks like it loads everything fine. But it has zero effect. I can make myself not an op. The prefix doesn't show up whether I am or am not a student.. (should the group be student or students? I tried both).

Comment: Ok, I kind of got this to work. First, not even `op`s can do the `/pex` command. That seems to have to be run on the server itself. But then I was able to add myself to the student group (adding myself to a group within the permissions.yml file doesn't work) and now I can't destroy anything. The colored chat prefix doesn't show up at all for default or student grouped users.

Comment: I'm just getting this setup on my server so I can test stuff out for you. Remember since you've set allowOps: false then ops are denied access to the pex command unless you explicitly allow it. I'll modify my answer in a sec to reflect how. When you add a user to a group with the pex command does it add it to the file for you?

Comment: Messed with this a bit, read the docs. I got it working I think well. Only issue now is the prefixes. I can issue the `/pex` command to set a prefix for a group and I get a positive response back, but I never see prefixes. That would be so helpful. After stopping the server I even see the `prefix:` line added to the permissions.yml file. But chatting doesn't show any prefix...

Comment: yes writing `pex user ...` on the server console enacted it and added it to the permissions.yml file.

Comment: Updated permissions with permissions.*, which will allow teacher users access to all pex commands.

Comment: https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/wiki/Pex-basics#wiki-pex-yaml-notes Has some notes on prefix format. Otherwise I can't think of anything, I've never had any problems with prefixes :/

Comment: What exactly happens with `prefix`? I copied the examples and still nothing. In Minecraft I type `t` and type a message, it just appears in white like normal, no prefix text or colors. Maybe it shows up normal for me, but with the `prefix` settings for everyone else?

Comment: It's a while since I configured a server with PEX< so I could be remembering wrong but I'm *fairly* certain that you can see your own prefix. You should see something like http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/multiprefix/ that, except obviously the how the prefix is styled depends on the settings you've configured.

Comment: Doh! It just occurred to me that I've always used ChatManager (another optional part of PEX, like ModifyWorld). You probably need that enabled for prefixes to work: https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx/wiki/ChatManager

Comment: that was it, I enabled ChatManager and now those prefixes work!

Comment: Woo! Is that everything working then?

Answer (score 1):

@at01 > ScriptCraft requires students to be ops. I know that may allow them to circumvent any permissions settings,

There's a new version of scriptcraft with a new classroom module which lets tutors turn on or off scripting for students. That is - it enables students to use ScriptCraft's Javascript interpreter without them being ops. Of course, smart students will quickly figure out how to make themselves ops using javascript.

See https://github.com/walterhiggins/ScriptCraft/blob/master/docs/API-Reference.md#classroom-plugin for more information.

Comment: Please make it clear that this is your script you are promoting. [Overt self promotion is not welcome](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)